# How do I revert the default mail client back to Mail from GMail?

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I downloaded Google Chrome and it automatically changed my default mail reader from Mail to GMail in Chrome. I went to the preferences section of Mail and didn't see an option to make Mail the default reader.

Answer (score 7):

This can be disabled in Google Chrome. Go to Settings, then select "Show Advanced Settings..." at the bottom of the page. Click "Content Settings", and click "Manage Handlers" under the "Handlers" heading. Under "Active protocol handlers", change mailto to "None".

Then go into Mail.app and into Preferences -> General, and make sure "Default E-mail Reader" to "Mail"

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it should work as described above. But for me it didn't, so I used RCDefaultApps prefpane to restore the handler for mailto back to Mail.app (on Snow Leopard).